# As3 Static Method Call Internal Method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, static, undefined

I downloaded a script from the internet and it works perfect. I started to adapt the code in it for a new application. But I get the following error **1061: Call to a possibly undefined method drawShape through a reference with static type Class.**

When looking at the code I see that the method that is calling drawShape is a static method calling it as such: **ShapeDrawer.drawShape();** Note that the ShapeDrawer class isn't being imported at all.

Then the drawShape method is as such: **internal function drawShape()** Can anyone explain to me why it may work in the application I downloaded and not mine. His was built for use with flash player 9 and mine is ten that may play a part.

This is what it looks like:

```
package puzzle
{
    import flash.geom.Point;    
    import utils.MyMath;

    public class PuzzleCaculater
    {
        public static function combineTwoPieces(pieceA:PuzzlePiece , pieceB:PuzzlePiece):void
        {
            for each(var drawingPiece in pieceB.unionPieces)
            {
                ShapeDrawer.drawShape(pieceA.graphicLayer , drawingPiece.shapeData , true);
                drawingPiece.disactive();
                drawingPiece.myGroup = pieceA.myGroup;
                drawingPiece.graphicLayer = pieceA.graphicLayer;
                pieceA.unionPieces.push(drawingPiece);
                drawingPiece.unionPieces = pieceA.unionPieces;
            }
        }
    }
}

package puzzle
{
    public class ShapeDrawer
    {
        internal function drawShape(target:Shape , drawingShapedata:Object , useBitmap:Boolean = true):void
        {
            var leftShape:Array= drawingShapedata.leftShape;
            var topShape:Array= drawingShapedata.topShape;
            var rightShape:Array= drawingShapedata.rightShape;
            var bottomShape:Array= drawingShapedata.bottomShape;
            var shapes:Array= [];
            shapes.push(leftShape);
            shapes.push(topShape);
            shapes.push(rightShape);
            shapes.push(bottomShape);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is PuzzleCaculater the correct spelling?

Comment: It's obviously spelled wrong, but that's how it was spelling the script. I verified that one a couple times.

Comment: Is the original script publicly available? If so, can we get a link?

Comment: It's not, sorry. It was a paid script so I don't believe I have the ability to give it publicly. I tried contacting the author about the issue but I haven't gotten a reply

Comment: Ok, so regardless of why it worked in the original, can you make it work in your version if you set drawShape to static internal?

Comment: Yeah, I have switched it but it brings on many errors. So I think I am going get my money back cause it doesn't seem to work like it's supposed to.

Comment: You would need to change all your vars to static vars for a Static version to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `drawShape` like this:

```
internal function drawShape(...)
```

And you must define it like this:

```
static internal function drawShape(...)
```

Thath will fix your problem, the `internal` keyword isn't the problem (because both classes are in the same package)

Comment: My main question or concern is why would it work on the original script that I downloaded but when I copy the exact code over to my application.

Comment: I don't know the difference of the two versions, maybe if you shows us both codes we can tell you why works in one and no in the other.

Comment: The code I pasted above is the exact code from both. I just copied an pasted it to my application.

Comment: Well, in that case I have to tell you that niether of codes works, maybe where you copy it they forget to type the `static` keyword. Or maybe (I doubt so) they call the function by an instance, like: `new ShapeDrawer().drawShape(...)`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought but there are not instances of it being created. I am going to continue to contact the author. Cause it doesn't make sense. I added the static Keyword and it threw many other errors.

Comment: No idea why. Without the whole code I can't tell you anything more than I posted in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The internal keyword will prevent this function from being called outside of the package.  Try making it public and see if that fixes it.

Comment: That is the weird thing though, the application that I downloaded works perfect as is. I want to know why.

Comment: Are you creating your own classes for your application? At the top of the classes you downloaded I assume there's a line like: `package com.something` If your class isn't in the com.something package, then it won't be able to access the method.  You can either change the method to public, or add your classes to the existing package.

Comment: Yes, they are both in the exact same package. That's what blows my mind. There are other functions that are called the same way that don't throw an error just that one. It's really strange.

Comment: Wait, is drawShape() actually a static method?

Comment: Declaring it as public didn't fix it. Keep in mind in the code I downloaded (that works) the class isn't instantiated. It is being called as though it were static.

Comment: No it's not, it is internal, it's just being called as though it were static.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [access modifiers](http://flexcomps.wordpress.com/2008/04/30/access-modifiers-in-as3/). They are critical to OO design patterns in AS3 (and other OO languages), and a misunderstanding of them will cause troubles ;)

> Internal: The internal methods or
>   properties are build to be shared
>   across a common package. You need not
>   to extend or inherit to the classes
>   having Internal members(Where as we do
>   inherit in case of protected) for
>   accessing them. The internal
>   members/methods are like public to the
>   classes those are in same package

Declaring this method as Public will most likely fix your sitch... Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I understand what they do. There are similar functions being called and they don't throw an error. They classes are all in the same package so that's what makes it even more strange

Comment: Declaring it as public didn't fix it. Keep in mind in the code I downloaded (that works) the class isn't instantiated. It is being called as though it were static.

Comment: I see that. Definitely called as a Static. And you say this code works?